# native browser plugins alternatives to NPAPI

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, npapi, google-nativeclient, browser-plugin

Hello as you might now NPAPI is deprecated.

What are the alternatives to this? I see skype released now the web version where you need to install a web plugin to make voice and video calls. Looking over what I installed I arrived to the conclusion that on chrome they are using Google Native Client: https://developer.chrome.com/native-client

But this one is not supported on firefox/safari (only chrome).

On Firefox/Safary I'm not sure what they are using.

So what are now the best alternatives for this kind of job where using c++ is mandatory (to extend an existing app and make it available as web plugin)

Silviu

Comment: Which APIs you're trying to use usually dictate what's appropriate. If you want normal web APIs with C++ then you can use Emscripten (or PNaCl on Chrome) and you don't need a plugin/extension or any installation. IF you want to use particular priviledged APIs which aren't exposed on the web then I suggest you clarify your question.

Answer (score 0):

After Chrome drop the NPAPI support, there is no-common technology support by Firefox/Chrome/Safari. You can consider about [Firebreath 2.0](http://www.firebreath.org/display/documentation/FireBreath+2.0%3A+Browser+Plugins+in+a+post-NPAPI+world). It allow you use one C++ implement to support different browser.
It's not released yet... If you like to try version 2.0, you can get source code from https://github.org/firebreath/firebreath (the "refactor" branch)

Note: version 2.0 make huge change, because the call between plugin and javascript are asynchronous! Upgrade from older version required lots of javascript change.